# Why don't VPN services use TLS?

Tags: tls, vpn

In corporate environment, security examiners use filters & firewalls to block VPN connections for security purpose.

VPN traffic is distinguishable and that's also the reason why openVPN doesn't work over The Great Firewall Of China. Then why not VPN channels use TLS? It'll then become impossible to predict which traffic belong to the VPN server as most of the traffic crossing filter is HTTPS to which filter has to allow.

Comment: OpenVPN uses TLS. As @gowenfawr points out however, VPN traffic, even over TLS,  can be distinguished from HTTPS traffic.

Comment: In addition to OpenVPN, Juniper, F5, Cisco all sell VPN products that can use TLS, and using them that way is fairly popular because it reduces admin hassles. I think the premise of this question is completely false.

Comment: @hobbs None of them work over the **The Great Firewall of China**. I wonder why.  I thought VPN over TLS was a good idea.

Comment: @user334283 I'm not sure why you think that. OpenVPN worked fine last time I visited.

Comment: @tangrs I heard that openVPN doesn't work in china.

Comment: Just to clarify; OpenVPN does work with the great firewall of China. I am using it right now in order to access google in order to do my work as a developer. Youtube works fine with it as well.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are a few things to undestand.

The first is that most VPN tools were originally designed to provide private connectivity over networks that were insecure, possiblly natted or firewalled but not actively hostile to VPNs.

The second is that traditional TLS is a wrapper over TCP. TCP is a poor choice for VPNs because it suffers from "head of line blocking". If one packet gets lost then all the data behind it is blocked until it is successfully retransmitted. This used to cause big problems when running VPNs over TCP, it's less of an issue now that we have TCP fast retransmission but it's still less than ideal.

The third is that deep packet inspection is a fairly new thing. Networks that will pass legitimate TLS traffic unmolested but that will not pass other traffic on port 443 are still the exception not the rule.

---

While Openvpn does have a TCP option it is primerally designed to run over UDP. It uses TLS for key exchange but encrypts the actual network packets using a system designed explicitly for that purpose.

https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/security-overview.html

---

> Someone should say something about DTLS (TLS over UDP) too

DTLS is a pretty new protcol. I see no reason why you couldn't/shouldn't build a VPN soloution on top of it but I guess the VPN software vendors aren't especially in the mood to redesign their software.

In any case it wouldn't help with the scenario described in the question.

Comment: +1 looks like a much better answer than the other one...

Comment: Someone should say something about DTLS (TLS over UDP) too

Comment: +1 "TCP is a poor choice for VPNs because it suffers from "head of line blocking"." - what worst the inner TCP might try to retransmit flooding network with duplicated packets so not only everything is waiting but the amount of things waiting increase in such case,

Comment: AIUI "fast retransmits" mitigates that because the "outer TCP" will see a sequence with a missing packet and retransmit before the "inner TCP" times out and tries to retransmit.

Comment: I don't think deep packet inspection is going to work on end-to-end TLS encrypted VPN traffic. They only can see the IP/Port of destination VPN server. Is it possible if VPN server uses port 443 while using TLS because then it'll become impossible to detect it.

Comment: @user334283: Shallow socket inspection can detect VPN traffic of any type because unlike regular HTTP traffic the VPN traffic is persistent/long-lived (unlike someone visiting Wikipedia or Facebook), non-sustained (long periods of no packets sent unlike video streaming) and bidirectional (unlike mostly client->server like file upload also unlike mostly server->client like video streaming). These traffic patterns would look "weird" to a firewall and you can write a script to drop the socket if you detect this. I used to work for a router manufacturer and our routers could do this.

Comment: DTLS isn't that new, and Cisco's AnyConnect is entirely based on it (with HTTPS for the initial handshake).

Comment: @grawity: Cisco AnyConnect uses HTTPS for authentication, and *prefers* DTLS for the tunnel, but can also fall back to HTTPS/TLS-only. (I'm a contributor to the FLOSS [openconnect](http://www.infradead.org/openconnect/) implementation.) I believe F5 and Citrix also sell HTTPS+DTLS VPN software.

Answer (score 20):

**Short version:**

- VPN protocols need to provide encapsulation that TLS doesn't provide
- Of course, it's possible to tunnel VPN over TLS to get the same effect!

**Long version:**

The name Virtual Private Network suggests the answer to your question.  A true VPN protocol emulates a Network, which implies the ability to route multiple traffic types and ports simultaneously over a single channel.  That's why with a VPN protocol like IPSec you can end up with, for example, TCP packets encapsulated within ESP packets encapsulated within other TCP packets.  (See also [What's the difference between SSH and IPsec?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/45439/3365))

By default TLS doesn't provide this capability.  TLS takes bytes, encrypts them, and transfers them to the recipient who can decrypt it.  That's it; everything else that's to be done has to be done by the application.  Under HTTPS, a web server and client exchange HTTP data bytes over a TLS channel.  Under IMAPS, a mail server and client exchange IMAP data bytes over a TLS channel.

In order to have generic "Network" connectivity over TLS, you need a client and server able to do that encapsulation and decapsulation on either end.  You don't get it for free.

That's not to say you can't have a VPN that runs over TLS.  There are many products that do it; even mainline vendors like Checkpoint support both IPSec and TLS-based VPNs.  In some cases the TLS is simply encapsulating IPSec datagrams, so the actual "N" is via IPSec but the TLS gets it across the Internet.

Note that in some cases a sophisticated adversary can infer when a TLS connection is being used for VPN based on the pattern of communication.  There's more to Operational Security than encrypting bits!

Comment: You don't really need to "encapsulate" IP packets to turn them into a bytestream. They have a length field already so you can just concatenate them at the sender and use the length field to chop them up at the receiver.

Comment: @PeterGreen, true. Each IP packet (up to 16k in size) can simply be converted into a TLS record. TLS libraries are supposed to guarantee that clients never read a partial record. Nevertheless, all the TLS-based VPNs I'm familiar with (e.g. [Cisco AnyConnect and PAN GlobalProtect](https://gitlab.com/openconnect/openconnect/blob/master/openconnect-internal.h#L138-145)) do include a simple header with a (redundant) length field, and in some cases additional information such as [EtherType](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EtherType). Possibly based on historical encapsulation in non-TLS protocols…?

Answer (score 11):

Many VPN protocols *do* use TLS. In particular, almost all of the modern client-server VPNs (e.g. used to connect a laptop remotely to a corporate network) support TLS as a primary or fallback transport.

I'm a contributor to the well-known open-source client for TLS/SSL based VPNs: [openconnect](http://www.infradead.org/openconnect). I reverse-engineered the GlobalProtect VPN protocol (TLS+ESP) almost entirely on my own. I've studied enough VPN protocols in detail to notice some pretty clear patterns and design tradeoffs.

## Advantages of TLS for VPN authentication and transport:

- Robustness. TLS-based VPN traffic is indistinguishable from "normal" HTTPS traffic in terms of its packet structure and encrypted contents — though timing and size of packets, and duration of connections, hint that it's carrying something other than "normal" browser traffic. The universality of HTTPS means that TLS-based VPNs can get through almost all firewalls and middleboxes; only really determined censors who do traffic analysis, or blacklist VPN endpoints by DNS or IP, can block it.
- Strong security guarantees: modern TLSv1.2 (soon, 1.3) is a very well-designed, carefully analyzed, and gradually-matured protocol for secure communications. Many libraries wrap it in a way that makes it fairly hard to misuse. If you use a TLS-based VPN, you can expect that your connection to the gateway uses modern ciphers (no ancient 1DES, for example) and x509 public-key certificate verification of the gateway, limiting man-in-the-middle attacks. It's *possible* to screw up the implementation of TLS, badly breaking its security, but *relatively* difficult due to the standardization of high-quality libraries which do most of the tricky bits. **It would be much, much easier to write an insecure VPN based on a "custom" protocol.**

## Disadvantages of TLS for VPN *transport*, compared to [ESP](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulating_Security_Payload) (the normal transport layer of IPSEC-based VPNs):

- TLS normally runs over TCP, which performs poorly as a tunneling transport with congested or lossy underlying network conditions… [especially in the case of TCP-over-TCP](http://sites.inka.de/bigred/devel/tcp-tcp.html).
- Fortunately, [DTLS](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/DTLS) ("datagram TLS") can alleviate this; it's used most prominently in the AnyConnect/openconnect VPN protocol, as well as in real-time communications protocols like WebRTC.
- Most modern operating systems have optimized in-kernel support for IPSEC and ESP. This makes ESP *really efficient* and low-overhead for gateways and firewalls and end-client systems, when implemented properly. TLS is typically implemented in userspace, and combined with the complexity of the underlying TCP stream, this makes it less efficient.
- (A similarly efficient in-kernel implementation of **D**TLS should be
  possible, but I'm not aware of any in a mainstream operating system.)

… as far as using TLS for the authentication/setup of a VPN? I basically see no real disadvantages there, other than the lack of standardized protocol for it.

TLS is more flexible, widely-implemented, and easier to debug than [ISAKMP](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/ISAKMP) (the authentication/key exchange component of IPSEC). Several modern corporate VPN protocols, including GlobalProtect, use **TLS for authentication and key exchange** but then **ESP for data transport** (though they can fall back to TLS if needed). This is a pretty effective and efficient combination, in my experience.